# Use Google Drive API with Laravel

Tags: php, api, laravel, google-drive-api

I want to use the Google Drive API in my Laravel project to store PDFs. Unfortunately, the example code is for common PHP and I don't know how could I implement it in Laravel.

```
<?php
  require_once 'Google/Client.php';
  require_once 'Google/Service/Books.php';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
  $client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_APP_KEY");
  $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
  $optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
  $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);

  foreach ($results as $item) {
    echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
  }
```

I guess that I have to include https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client in my dependencies, but I don't know how can I acces to the functions of the API.

Can anybody help me?

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For login + file upload on drive (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/large-file-upload.php)

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
include_once "templates/base.php";
session_start();

set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';

/************************************************
  We'll setup an empty 20MB file to upload.
 ************************************************/
DEFINE("TESTFILE", 'testfile.txt');
if (!file_exists(TESTFILE)) {
  $fh = fopen(TESTFILE, 'w');
  fseek($fh, 1024*1024*20);
  fwrite($fh, "!", 1);
  fclose($fh);
}

/************************************************
  ATTENTION: Fill in these values! Make sure
  the redirect URI is to this page, e.g:
  http://localhost:8080/fileupload.php
 ************************************************/
$client_id = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
$client_secret = '<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>';
$redirect_uri = '<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token ']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

/************************************************
  If we're signed in then lets try to upload our
  file.
 ************************************************/
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->title = "Big File";
  $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

  // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
  $client->setDefer(true);
  $request = $service->files->insert($file);

  // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
  $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
      $client,
      $request,
      'text/plain',
      null,
      true,
      $chunkSizeBytes
  );
  $media->setFileSize(filesize(TESTFILE));

  // Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
  // complete.
  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen(TESTFILE, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
  }

  // The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object
  // that has been uploaded.
  $result = false;
  if ($status != false) {
    $result = $status;
  }

  fclose($handle);
}
echo pageHeader("File Upload - Uploading a large file");
if (
    $client_id == '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>'
    || $client_secret == '<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>'
    || $redirect_uri == '<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>') {
  echo missingClientSecretsWarning();
}
?>
<div class="box">
  <div class="request">
    <?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
      <a class='login' href='<?php echo $authUrl; ?>'>Connect Me!</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <?php if (isset($result) && $result): ?>
    <div class="shortened">
      <?php var_dump($result); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif ?>
</div>
<?php
echo pageFooter(__FILE__);
```

Comment: How to get $_SESSION['upload_token'] from laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel utilises Composer to handle dependencies. Add `google/apiclient` as a dependency in your composer.json file.

Comment: Yes, I have done it. But I don't know how to call the functions in my controllers.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    require_once "protected/vendor/google-api-php/Google/Client.php";
    require_once "protected/vendor/google-api-php/Google/Service/Drive.php

    $client = new Google_Client();

    $dr_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

    $mimetype = 'application/pdf';
    $uploadType = 'media';
    $filetitle = $file_name;
    $filedescription = 'Taskew ' . $model['discussion_title'];

    $datetime = date('d-m-y-h:s');

    $file->setTitle($datetime . $filetitle);
    $file->setDescription($filedescription);
    $file->setMimeType($mimetype);

    $data = file_get_contents($folder . $file_name);

    $createdFile = $dr_service->files->insert($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'mimeType' => $mimetype, //text/plain',
    'uploadType' => $uploadType
    ));
```

Comment: Google_Service_Exception in REST.php , login required, error num 401