# Upload file Laravel 4 and Google API

Tags: laravel, google-api, google-drive-api, google-client

Hello I am currently working on an application that uses Google drive. I am trying to integrate it to my Google API. I already have a Google-API-client library in my vendor folder. How do i call the class because i am using another service provider as my authentication. So do i have to declare the client id, client secret and scope again? I tried "use Google_Client as client". I get an error "trying to access non object function"

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link :

[Use Google Drive API with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778296/use-google-drive-api-with-laravel)

Also this,

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client